# File download from the browser via DB has extra bytes added causing corruption messages from microsoft applications

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, browser

```
 <%
    Document downloadFile = null;
    String mimeType = null;
    try{
        downloadFile = new DocumentsDao().loadById(Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("id")));

        // gets MIME type of the file
        mimeType = downloadFile.getFileType();
        if (mimeType == null) {        
            // set to binary type if MIME mapping not found
            mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
        }
        System.out.println("MIME type: " + mimeType);
    }catch (Exception e){
        return;
    }

    // modifies response
    response.reset();
    response.resetBuffer();
    response.setContentType(mimeType);
    response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.getDocumentData().length);

    // forces download
    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
    String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", downloadFile.getFileName());
    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

    // obtains response's output stream
    OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int bytesRead = -1;
    System.out.println("### Length from db = "+downloadFile.getDocumentData().length);
    ByteArrayInputStream inStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(downloadFile.getDocumentData());

    while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    inStream.close();
    outStream.close();  
    response.flushBuffer();
    return;
    %>
```

The above code in a JSP produces a file to download which has an additional sequence of 0d0a x 4 at the end which causes the microsoft applications word and excel to complain and have to repair the file which has been downloaded.

I thought it might be the upload of the file but it was not, and retrieving from the database is fine. So the input stream is fine the problem occurs after the output stream is closed.

Errors you get are 'Word found unreadable content' 'Excel found unreadable content'

Has anyone seen this?

cheers

Charlie

Answer (score 0):

The conversion of the JSP to servlet introduced the 0d0a X 4 characters. I used fiddle to find that the Apache Tomcat web server was altering the content length and sending the bytes. I looked at working apps at work and they all used servlets to do the job so I converted the above code to a servlet and it worked perfectly.

So don't use JSPs for this purpose.